# How to get different values selected on selectInput

Tags: select, input, shiny

I want to introduce my csv data into this application which is appended to this question: what I'm aiming to is to make sure that the two select Input are loaded with different values whatever the user's selecting! The problem with my code is that the first selectInput is blocked to the same initial value while it must change and prevent the second to have its value every time !

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
    htmlOutput("variables"),
    htmlOutput("facteurs"),
    uiOutput("tb"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myData1 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,row.names=1)
    data
  })
  output$variables <- renderUI({
    df_init <- myData1() 
    x=sapply(df_init,class)
    x=(x=="numeric")
    df=df_init[,x]
    if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
    selectInput(inputId = "V1", label = "Variables to use: Y", choices=names(df), selected=names(df[1]))
  })
  output$facteurs <- renderUI({
    df_init <- myData1() 
     x=sapply(df_init,class)
    x=(x=="factor")
    df=df_init[,x]
    if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
       verticalLayout(
        selectInput(inputId = "F11", label = "Factors to use: X1", choices=names(df)),
        selectInput(inputId = "F12", label = "Factors to use: X2", choices=names(df)[names(df)!=input$F11]))
   })}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The data is

```
,Var,Lo,ES,Acidity,K232,K270,IP,OS,C 14:0,C 16:0,C 16:1,C 17:0,C 17:1,C 18:0,C 18:1,C 18:2,C 18:3,C 20:0,C 20:1,total,LLL,LnLO,LnLP,LLO,LnOO,PLL,LOO,LOP,PLP,OOO,POP,POO,AOL,SOO,SOP,Chlorophyll,b carotène,polyphenols ,Ethyl acetate,2- Methyl butanal,3- Methyl butanal,1-Penten-3-one,3-Hexanone,Hexanal,3-Pentanol,Trans-2-pentenal,1-Penten-3-ol,Cis-3-hexenal,Trans-2-hexenal,1-Pentanol,Hexyl acetate,Cis-3-hexenyl acetate,Cis-2-pentenol,6-Methyl-5-hepten-2-one,1-Hexanol,Trans-3-hexenol,Cis-3-hexenol,Trans-2-hexenol,Acetic acid,Butyric acid,H-   Tyr      ,Tyr ,DFOA,DFLA,Ac-Pin,Pin,EAA,OA,LA,total phenols (HPLC)
P1,chetoui,beja,sp,0.93,1.49,0.2,9.2,16.51,0.01,13.5,0.57,0.07,0.08,2.57,67.04,18.56,1.16,0.02,0.39,103.95,0.72,0.45,0.1,7.87,2.63,0.38,22.14,8.8,0.7,33.47,15.84,1.77,0.37,3.95,0.8,5.05,4.1,491.6,2.72,0.29,0.11,0.08,0.1,15.27,1.35,1.55,3.77,22.68,133.13,0.36,9.92,7.14,2.37,0.5,10.03,0.78,121.11,14.12,0.05,0.08,1.91,4.15,10.33,40.52,1.21,5.5,2.92,30.65,2.35,99.53
P2,chetoui,beja,sp,0.36,1.24,0.2,8.2,16.81,0.01,13.39,0.18,0.05,0.07,1.23,69.23,18.63,0.91,0.02,0.28,104,0.69,0.43,0.15,7.81,2.57,0.42,22.21,8.84,0.71,33.87,15.6,2.01,0.38,4.14,1.01,5.88,6.161,457.04,2.52,0.34,0.12,0.09,0.22,15.2,1.32,1.52,3.67,22.61,133.19,0.35,9.89,7.18,2.34,0.51,10.17,0.75,121.21,14.29,0.05,0.02,1.92,4.05,10.45,40.63,1.25,5.55,2.95,31.042,2.17,100.01
P3,chetoui,beja,sp,0.84,1.87,0.21,8.6,16.73,0.01,13.31,0.45,0.06,0.08,2.54,69.29,17.03,0.84,0.02,0.37,104,0.72,0.42,0.12,7.82,2.61,0.43,21.22,8.83,0.72,33.85,15.52,1.92,0.39,4.05,0.95,5.92,6.241,482.12,2.72,0.25,0.08,1.12,0.42,15.01,1.3,1.44,3.93,22.51,133.07,0.39,9.87,7.16,2.31,0.52,10.1,0.76,121.29,14.21,0.06,0.01,1.93,4.12,10.6,40.71,1.26,5.54,2.96,30.43,2.26,99.81
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. **I am a pro in `shiny` and as it currently stands this question is impossible to answer. I recommend to put this question on hold until further details are provided.** Please edit your question to include all the code of your `shiny`-app. In addition you need to describe **exactly** what you want to do and provide/describe some sample data as well. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome! A reproducible example would have been helpful, indeed. On server side you could use smthg like `output$UIF12 <- renderUI(selectInput(inputId = "F12", label = "Factors to use: X2", choices = setdiff(outVar, input$F11))))` and on ui side, sthg like: `uiOutput("UIF12")`,...

Comment: I've updated the question to a better way !